# Problems adding dynamic data to UL jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-cordova

I have this ul

```
  <ul data-role="listview" id="contributionList" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
    <li id="l1"><a>5.00</a><a id="1" class="deleteMe"></a></li>
    <li><a>10.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>                        
  </ul>
```

I'm trying to add data dynamically to it. But for reasons I don't understand, it doesn't take the class `deleteme`.

This is how I'm trying to fill it:

```
 $('#OkTarget').bind("click tap", function () {        
     $('#contributionList').append('<li id="lii1"><a>5.00</a><a id="aid1" class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');                       
 });
```

This is what is supossed to be done when it click:

```
$('.deleteMe').bind("click tap", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#contributionList').listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate for elements added dynamically. Try

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.deleteMe', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#contributionList').listview('refresh');
});
```

instead of

```
$('.deleteMe').bind("click tap", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#contributionList').listview('refresh');
});
```

`bind` will attach events to only existing elements with that selector when it is executed

Comment: said this error 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: @sgrysoft, ah, that is because you are using an older version of jquery. Use delegate instead like `$(document).delegate('.deleteMe', 'click tap',  function () {....`

Comment: ohhh dammm, awsome, it works, but can you tell me wich is the correct actual version that i have to use (link preferible if its posible) to use it like you told me first??

Comment: so, i have to download the "2.1.4¨version and will be best right?